# Type info required in a class that's not actually using that type

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

So I'm having the following files, with the following content:

a.h :

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

class A {
};

#endif
```

b.h :

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include <memory>

class A;

class B {
public:
    B(std::unique_ptr<A> a);
private:
    std::unique_ptr<A> a_;
};
#endif
```

b.cpp :

```
#include "b.h"
#include "a.h"

B::B(std::unique_ptr<A> a) : a_(std::move(a)) {
}
```

c.h :

```
#ifndef C_H
#define C_H

#include "b.h"

class C {
public:
    void add_b(std::unique_ptr<B> b);

private:
    std::unique_ptr<B> b_;
};

#endif
```

c.cpp:

```
#include "c.h"

void C::add_b(std::unique_ptr<B> b) {
    b_ = std::move(b);
}
```

And a file containing an empty main method. As you can see in `b.h` I'm not actually including `a.h` since I'm using only pointers in the class declaration and that's not necessary, only a declaration being enough - `class A;`. If i try to compile this using gcc I'm getting an error that states something like:

> In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/memory:81:0,
>                    from b.h:4,
>                    from c.h:4,
>                    from c.cpp:1:
>   error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘A’
>   static_assert(sizeof(_Tp)>0

When I saw the part with "incomplete type 'A'" I figured out that `class C` needs more info about `A` since it's not aware of it's existence because it's only including `b.h` which only uses a declaration for A (`class A;`). Obviously including `a.h` header in `c.cpp` solved the error, but then I realized that `A` is not actually involved in the visible implementation of `C` class. Why does `C` need to know more info about `class A`? What's actually happening? I think this is very obscure and hard to follow. How can I avoid such situations? The original example was much more convoluted so I had to actually dig and simplify this. I was just trying to have a minimal header file with necessary info only, avoiding unnecessary macro expansions.

Answer (score 2):

> but then I realized that A is not actually involved in the visible implementation of C class. Why does C need to know more info about class A?

Implicitly `class A` needs to be seen with the implementation of `class B` as required from

```
 std::unique_ptr<B> b_;
```

in `class C`, hence the error.

It doesn't matter if `A` is visible by means of the `public` parts of `class B`. `class B` must be fully declared at that point, which includes a full declaration of `class A` in turn.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because std::unique_ptr is sizeof-ing the underlying incomplete type A.  Obviously, to get the sizeof a type, the type has to be defined.

The reason the unique_ptr is sizeof-ing the underlying type is because of `std::default_delete<A>`.  If you override the default deleter for the unique_ptr, you can make it so it doesn't sizeof the underlying type, and you can make it compile without the type being complete.

Example...

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class A;

struct Deleter {
    void operator()(A* ptr) const {
        std::cout << "I'm supposed to delete A but I'm a liar!" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<A, Deleter> a(reinterpret_cast<A*>(1));
}
```

This compiles, links and runs just fine

Comment: It compiles fine - but now it's basically just `A*`.

Comment: Which is precisely what his question was.  He was asking why he gets incomplete type errors when he is only using a pointer... This is exactly the reason.